# Angular2 Call a method of Other class exist in same Typescript

Tags: angular

**I want to call a method of Class1 - sometMethod() from other method of Class2**

**How is that possible?**

Both Classes are exist in same Typescript.

```js
export class Class1 {

    constructor(public nav: NavController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    sometMethod() {
      console.log("someMethod of Class1");
    }
}


export class Class2 {

    constructor(public nav: NavController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    sometOtherMethod() {
      console.log("someOtherMethod of Class2");
      //I want to call a method of Class1 - sometMethod()
      //How is that possible?
      //Class1.someMethod(); //Does not Worked!!
    }
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: What are the purposes of these classes? Are they Angular2 Components, Services? How do the two classes relate to each other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either you create an instance of class1 in class2, and then you call the class1 method from the instance, or you can make the method static, and then use it as you wrote.

Option 1:

```
export class Class1 {
    constructor(public nav: NavController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    sometMethod() {
      console.log("someMethod of Class1");
    }
}

export class Class2 {
    constructor(public nav: NavController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    sometOtherMethod() {
      console.log("someOtherMethod of Class2");
      let class1Instance = new Class1(this.nav, this.formBuilder, this.viewCtrl);
      class1Instance.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
export class Class1 {
    constructor(public nav: NavController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    static sometMethod() {
      console.log("someMethod of Class1");
    }
}

export class Class2 {
    constructor(public nav: NavController, public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
        this.nav = nav;
    }

    sometOtherMethod() {
      console.log("someOtherMethod of Class2");
      Class1.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ophir, thanks for Help!
Option1 worked for me - created an instance of class.

Problem with Option2: it won't be able to access other members of Class2 using this!
static sometOtherMethod(categId: string) {
        this.memberOfClass2 = categId;
}

Comment: Perfect answer, I was so stuck on this ! However, could you provide some explanation about the fact that there is no way to call a class method for a given instance ? No way to cast this instance into a "real" object of its own class ? There is not a word about this in the Angular documentations, that's confusing. Is this an anti-pattern ? (and if so, what is the correct way to manipulate data from a service accessing any object ?)

Comment: Orabîg, I didn't quite understand what are you trying to do. Do you want to call a static method of a class from a class instance?